# I need some clarification on Virtual directory in IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

OK. Maybe I am not doing this right but I can tell you what I am doing and maybe someone can help.

I have my application located in http:\localhost\MyApplication ( c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication).
Now I have a virtual directory created in http:\localhost\MyApplication\ImagePaths ( pointing to d:\images folder)

within one of my aspx pages I am trying to list all the images in http:\localhost\MyApplication\ImagePaths virtual Directory.
I have tried:
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/ImagePaths")); Dir contains c:\inetpub\wwwroot\images !!??!?!?

What is the right way of doing this?  I just want to create a directory outside of my application and list the content within my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would use `<appSettings>` section of the web.config and store it there:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ImagesPath" value="D:\Images"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then from code, you can access it via:

```
string imagesPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesPath"];
```

and:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(imagesPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ~ means "from the root of my virtual directory". You're then building a path from there, that doesn't exist, and asking for the location of it on disk.

You'll get an answer to that even if the folder doesn't exist.

Why not use configuration to state where the images can be found, rather than hard coding a virtual directory? Your current approach would his issues as soon as you host those vdirs on separate machines anyway, so it's better to use config to store the unc path.

Comment: Sure I am open to that.  How do I use configuration.  I am new to this.  Cheers